# How do I combine url for my beautifulsoup project?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, concatenation

This is the code that I have so far :

```
from grp import struct_group
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   
import requests 
import pandas as pd   
import urllib.parse 

name = []
price = []
mileage = []
dealer_name =[]
source = []



for i in range (1,13):
        #Allow to Crawl multiple pages:
        website ='https://www.cars.com/shopping/results/?page=' + str(i) + '&page_size=20&dealer_id=&keyword=&list_price_max=&list_price_min=&makes[]=&maximum_distance=all&mileage_max=&sort=best_match_desc&stock_type=used&year_max=&year_min=&zip=95355'
        #Requesting using requests lib 
        response = requests.get(website)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        #Finding results 
        results = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'vehicle-card'})   
        url_combine = []
        root_url = 'http://www.cars.com'   
        url_combine = root_url , source
        
        
        for result in results:    
            # name
            try:
                name.append(result.find('h2').get_text()) 
            except:
                name.append('n/a')
            #price 
            try:
                price.append(result.find('span', {'class':'primary-price'}).get_text())
            except:
                price.append('n/a')
            
            # mileage
            try:
                mileage.append(result.find('div', {'class':'mileage'}).get_text())
            except:
                mileage.append('n/a')
            # dealer_name
            try:
                dealer_name.append(result.find('div', {'class':'dealer-name'}).get_text().strip())
            except:
                dealer_name.append('n/a')
            #link
            try:
                source.append(result.find('a', {'class':'vehicle-card-visited-tracking-link'}).get('href'))
            except:
                source.append('n/a')
        for link in source:
            url_combine.append(urllib.parse.urljoin(root_url, link))
            

#Using Pandas to create a dictionary and import to Excel
car_listings = pd.DataFrame({'Name': name, 'Mileage':mileage, 'Price': price, 'Dealer Name':dealer_name,'Link': source})
car_listings.to_excel('car_listings_page4.xlsx')
```

However, I keep running into prolem where it says that `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'`.

I know I need to make everything a `list` instead of a `tuple` but I can't seem to find where my mistake is. I believe this is one way to get the full url from `href`. If so, is there any other way I can implement into my code?

Comment: `url_combine = root_url , source` - that's a tuple, remove or edit that line so that `url_combine.append(urllib.parse.urljoin(root_url, link))` doesn't give error

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3):

*Avoid all these `lists` and use `dicts` instead, simplify and store info in more structured way - You could also use `if-statement`.*

There are various ways to perform string concatination:

- `+` operator
- `join()` method
- `%` operator
- `format()` function
- `f-string` literal string interpolation (check in example for assignment
  to `website`)

However simplest one is using `+` operator:

```
root_url+link
```

Concerning my example using `dicts` it would look like:

```
'link': root_url+result.find('a', {'class':'vehicle-card-visited-tracking-link'}).get('href') if result.find('a', {'class':'vehicle-card-visited-tracking-link'}) else None
```

or a bit shorter with `walrus operator` (Python 3.8 and later):

```
'link': root_url+a.get('href') if (a:=result.find('a', {'class':'vehicle-card-visited-tracking-link'})) else None
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

root_url = 'http://www.cars.com'
data = []

for i in range (1,2):
        website =f'https://www.cars.com/shopping/results/?page={i}&page_size=20&dealer_id=&keyword=&list_price_max=&list_price_min=&makes[]=&maximum_distance=all&mileage_max=&sort=best_match_desc&stock_type=used&year_max=&year_min=&zip=95355'
        response = requests.get(website)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        results = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'vehicle-card'})   

        for result in results:

            data.append({
                'name': result.find('h2').get_text() if result.find('h2') else None,
                'price': result.find('span', {'class':'primary-price'}).get_text() if result.find('span', {'class':'primary-price'}) else None,
                'link': root_url+a.get('href') if (a:=result.find('a', {'class':'vehicle-card-visited-tracking-link'})) else None
                ### all the other info
            })

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

##### Output

|  | name | price | link |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2017 Lexus IS 200t Base | $28,900 | http://www.cars.com/vehicledetail/6942c51b-c26c-4614-97f1-acb0b7517b82/ |
| 1 | 2021 Lincoln Corsair Reserve | $43,797 | http://www.cars.com/vehicledetail/e575219a-90fa-4a95-ade5-d2740e746cd0/ |
| 2 | 2021 Hyundai IONIQ Hybrid SE | $26,997 | http://www.cars.com/vehicledetail/716b65ec-3abd-42e4-b19b-9024d2ad58f1/ |
| 3 | 2021 GMC Yukon XL Denali | $74,888 | http://www.cars.com/vehicledetail/475045f6-142a-440f-80e7-2c3ae289fee2/ |
| 4 | 2007 Chevrolet Silverado 1500 | $12,688 | http://www.cars.com/vehicledetail/56080319-0bb9-49e0-8758-24f58d0d5d76/ |

...